# What is this five-note, repeating bass pattern called?

Tags: theory, terminology, accompaniment

[image: bass pattern image]

I'm looking for examples of this repeating pattern as a bass. Not these specific notes, but what is it called when you have five notes played quickly and many times?

Comment: Might depend on the accent pattern too.  If you stress the A and E here, then the remainder are semi-ornamental against the main  I - V-  I -V pattern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general term for a repeating bass figure is **ostinato**. It is rare to see a bass line moving in steady sixteenth notes, but it is very common to see bass lines moving at steady pulses in other notes values: wholes notes, half notes, quarter notes, and eighth notes. You mention that the notes are played quickly, so I'll focus on the last two notes values.

A steady bass line made up of quarter notes is often called a **walking bass line**. This is common is jazz, but it does not usually feature repeating phrases of five notes. Instead, walking bass lines in jazz tend to be less predicable.

A steady eighth note bass line is a characteristic of **[boogie woogie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boogie-woogie)**. One of the most characteristic boogie woogie bass lines closely matches the contour of your example.

Comment: Aren't those sixteenth notes?

Answer (score 4):

As a bass-line, this specific pattern doesn't have a special name. However, there are some terms that apply.

- **pentachord** or **pentascale**: a five-note scale

> a pentachord may be any consecutive five-note section of a diatonic scale. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentachord))

- **ostinato**: a repeating motif

> In music, an ostinato [ostiˈnaːto] (derived from Italian: stubborn, compare English, from Latin: 'obstinate') is a motif or phrase that persistently repeats in the same musical voice, frequently in the same pitch. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostinato))

Comment: I think a pentascale usually (-ish) implies a more equallly-spaced set of 5 pitches spanning an octave.  For this to be a pentascale, the last interval would be a Major 4th!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Pentascale is a five-note scale, usually major or minor (e.g., https://ultimatemusictheory.com/pentascale-or-pentatonic-scale); a pentatonic scale spans an octave